# XSLT: remove white spaces when transforming to HTML

Tags: html, xslt, whitespace, strip

I have a XML doc that is transformed to HTML but I want the result HTML to be as small as possible. So I must remove all white spaces and line endings. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

is a good idea.

So is specifying the details of the output:

```
<xsl:output
    indent="no"
    method="html"/>
```

If the above still are not good enough, you can try altering the processing of `text()` nodes (thinking along the lines of DocBook's schema, where any text you explicitly wanted would be in `<para/>` tags, or similar):

```
<xsl:template match="chapter/text()"/>
```

You can use just `match="text()"` but that might be too aggressive as it is very vague--it will not necessarily kill the text you want (again, in your `<para/>` tags, or similar) as those text nodes will probably be processed implicitly by XSLT's built in templates.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to use [`strip-space`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_preserve-space.asp):

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

`xsl:strip-space` will let you strip out whitespace from the result tree. Also make sure you don't generate extra whitespace in the stylesheet. That is, make sure instead of something like

```
<xsl:value-of select="@key"/>
:
<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
```

use `xsl:text`

```
<xsl:value-of select="@key"/>
<xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should go with

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```